# Should the existing close votes be shown in the review section?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, close-dialog

Pretty straightforward. Should the count be showed in the review section:

> [image]

Ok it shows what my peer reviewers have chosen.

- What are the real benefits of seeing that number **in a review queue**?

I don't think there are any.
Let's say I'm a robo-reviewer and I'm making suggested edits review:

- I can look in the Reject dialog to see if there are reasons to refuse the edit, choose the popular one, and move to my next *speed review*.
- I can look in the Reject dialog to make sure this is not an audit. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but audits never have that counter).

---

*Update:* After reading [juergen-d](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d)'s answer I realized that it is useful in the question's UI so that the OP can check why his question is being closed.

But for the reasons stated above, **should we remove the count from the review section**?

Comment: Well, as far a duplicates go, there are plenty of times where one could go to close a question as not constructive or any other reason, see the number next to the duplicate, and choose to close it as a duplicate of the suggested question instead. I've done quite a few times myself. The same could be said for an "off-topic belongs on" vote. Hmmm, maybe it *could* belong somewhere else.

Comment: +1 because I've always kind of liked the "do your own review" idea, instead of copying the votes of others. Though @animuson has a point and that has been my approach on various occasions as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A low quality reviewer can still just choose a reason at random instead of following the crowd if this is a serious problem.  If you really are concerned about this specific type of abuse then audits can be created in which the "other close votes" are for an invalid reason, thus resulting in the audit being failed if the user goes along with them.  You shouldn't be removing valuable information that good reviewers can use to make an informed decision just because it also helps bad reviewers make bad reviews.  They'll do bad stuff no matter what you do.

Personally I find the information *highly* useful and I look at it all the time.  If I find a particular post borderline having the opportunity to see what other people thought, and to consider their position, is very helpful.

Even more so, if I don't think a question should be closed (or a suggested edit rejected; same logic applies there as well) but I see some close votes then I'll want to see why they think it should be closed.  Perhaps I strongly disagree, perhaps I assumed they were voting for X reason, which isn't right, but they were actually voting for Y reason, which is fine.  (The best example of this is sometimes a question is just fantastic and I see no reason it should be closed, but it's in fact a dupe, which *is* an appropriate reason to close an otherwise great question.  Looking at the past votes helps explain that behavior.)

Comment: Good points. I approve

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't want to to close when I view that dialog. Maybe I just want to know why on earth my question is about being closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited my question :)